# My "avoid car" can't move straight

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, robotics

[image]

I use 2 gearbox motors with 2 wheels .. but if I try to run it, he can not walk straight. he always moves slightly to the right or to the left.

How i fix it ?

Comment: well you have posted no code, no schematics, no real information, so I guess we are to guess at how you have it all configured?  I would guess you are using PWM output to  control how fast the motors are going. So you should increase or decrease one to adjust the speed

Comment: I've tried it, do I need to use a "encoder motor" ?

Comment: What were the results when you tried it?  Did it work but you were not able to find the correct balance between the motors?  Encoders will help ensure they are spinning at the same rate yes, but other factors could still make the car turn slightly.

Comment: What, exactly, did you try, and what happened? Please show more details about how your car behaves, what you changed, whether the car's behavior changed at all, etc. There just isn't enough information here to offer you much more than guesses.

Comment: swap the motor wires just to make sure that the problem is the motor (it should still turn the same direction .... if the direction changes then it is the driver or the software

Answer (score 2):

Likely the two gearbox motors you have are running at slightly different speeds for the same voltage. This is probably within normal tolerances, given that you say it moves *slightly* to the right or left.

You can use PWM-capable pins for motor control so you can adjust how fast the motors turn. If you do this, you have a couple of paths you can take:

You can, through trial-and-error, lower the PWM value (`analogWrite(pin, speed)`) for the faster-turning motor so that they both turn at the same speed.

or

You can find some way to detect the actual rotational speed of each motor and do the calibration in real-time on the Arduino. This might mean adding new sensors such as rotary encoders (mechanical or optical), or light-break sensors, etc.

Comment: I will try it again , to find the same speed with PWM. But if that not work , what module can i use to the rotary encoder ?

Comment: To use the rotary encoder solution gets much more complex. You have to find a rotary encoder that can fit onto the same shaft as your motor or wheel, or obtain a motor/gearbox that has a built-in encoder.